# How do I define a custom collection interface in Scala without defining an implementation?

Tags: scala, scala-2.8, scala-collections

I'm trying to define a custom collection interface in Scala 2.8.  I want to require that subclasses be Traversable, plus some other behavior.  I also want methods like map() to return the appropriate type, as below:

```
trait CustomCollection[+A] extends Traversable[A] {
    def customOperation(i:Int):Int // for example
}

def incrementAll(c:CustomCollection[Int]):CustomCollection[Int] = c.map { _ + 1 }
```

This doesn't compile, because CustomCollection.map() returns a Traversable.  I suppose I need to define a CanBuildFrom, but then I need to define an apply() method that constructs an instance from scratch.  I don't want to specify a way to construct this; that should be up to the implementer.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want `map` to return a more specific collection type, then you should also inherit `TraversableLike`, with the second type parameter (representation type) set to `CustomCollection[A]`.

Next, `map` requires an implicit parameter of type `CanBuildFrom`. It will look in the companion object of `CustomCollection` to find a conforming implicit value of that type. If you take a look at the source code of `Seq` classes, you will see that their companions provide `CanBuildFrom` objects of type `GenericCanBuildFrom` which forwards the call for the builder back to the collection that requested the builder. That way, the dynamic type of return type of `Seq` transformer methods (e.g. `map`) is always the same as the type of the sequence itself.

What you have to do is:

1. Make `CustomCollection[A]` inherit `TraversableLike`
2. Make `CustomCollection[A]` inherit `GenericTraversableTemplate`
3. Make a companion object of `CustomCollection` and add an implicit which returns a `GenericCanBuildFrom`
4. Provide a default implementation for the builder in the `CustomCollection` companion

The implementers of `CustomCollection` will need to provide companion objects which have builder implementations and implicit `CanBuildFrom` objects (which can simply be `GenericCanBuildFrom`s).

EDIT:

`GenericTraversablTemplate` mentioned above is needed because it first ensures that the collection will have the `genericBuilder` method called by the `GenericCanBuildFrom` builder factory. Second, it ensures that the collection actually has the companion object of type `GenericCompanion`.

Comment: Thanks, axel22.  If I understand your answer, I need to provide a default implementation of CustomCollection, which will be used by my companion's newBuilder method.  I was hoping to avoid specifying a default implementation.  Could you elaborate on why I need one?  It doesn't seem like it should be necessary for a method like map(), because you can't call map() unless you already have some implementation.

Comment: Technically, you could avoid providing a default builder implementation in the `CustomCollection` companion, but then how do you implement the parameterless `apply()` method in the `CanBuildFrom`? You can let `newBuilder` in `CustomCollection` companion throw an unsupported operation exception, thus avoiding a default implementation. I believe everything would then work, except for the `breakOut` method in collections, which requires the parameterless `apply()`..

Comment: Ah... so the reason I need a default implementation is to make breakOut work.  Thanks!

Comment: Where did `GenericTraversableTemplate` come from? You didn't explain that.